# How to separate ng-template in separate file

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-template

I'm using [angularUI typehead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) for the input element. I'm using custom template to show the values. Its all working fine. My question is how do i separate the `ng-template` into a separate file so that it can be re-used in other files as well.

*In case my words are not clear, please note that I'm referring to `ng-templates` specifically and not concerned about separate other html content*

Here's the code:

```
 // custom template begin 
 // this is the ng-template
 // I'd like to move this custom template into to another file 
 // similar to partials
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
    <a>
        <b>{{match.model.name}}</b>
        <div>{{match.model.username}}</div>
    </a>
</script>
 //custom template end


// input element makes use of the ng-template defined above
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-2 control-label normal" for="assignTo">Assign To</label>
 <div class="col-md-3">
    <input name="bug_assignTo" id="bug_assignTo" ng-model="bug.assignTo" typeahead="user.username as user.name for user in config.users | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control input-sm" typeahead-on-select="bug.assignTo = $item" placeholder="type name" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html"></input>
 </div>
```

Putting it in a partial did not work, e.g:
`<div ng-include="app/client/bug/new/my-ng-template.partial.html"></div>`
throws:

```
Tried to load angular more than once.
 [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
...
....
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need `ng-include`.

Move the template into separate file, lets say the file name `customTemplate.html`
and file contents like

```
<a>
    <b>{{match.model.name}}</b>
    <div>{{match.model.username}}</div>
</a>
```

Don't include `<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">` tag when it is moved into separate file.

Use the correct file path like

```
<input name="bug_assignTo" 
               id="bug_assignTo" 
               ng-model="bug.assignTo" 
               typeahead="user.username as user.name for user in config.users | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" 
               class="form-control input-sm" 
               typeahead-on-select="bug.assignTo = $item" 
               placeholder="type name" 
               typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" /> <!--put correct physical path here, if it is inside partial folder then use partial/customTemplate.html-->
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but does the template make use of $templateCache for example when it's not in Script tag with type="text/template"?

Comment: Yes you can use $templateCache